# LaTeX on Gmail (GmailTex?)

Tags: packages

I added GmailTex to talk about math with my friends via Gmail. However even if I type something like `$3^n$`, it doesn't turn into a superscript (I confirmed it by sending an email to me.) Do I need to write something other than dollar sign?

(Also, I don't really know where to tag this question. I would appreciate any advice for that too)

Comment: GmailTeX is not really TeX: it's  a way of using TeX-like math markup in documents in a similar way to MathJaX. As such, questions about how it works (or doesn't) are off-topic for us: it does not actually involve TeX or a related typesetting engine. At the same time, as noted in the answer this is essentially a bug in GmailTeX due to changes in Chrome, which would make it 'too localized' (in time).

Comment: Check this thread [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/report-an-issue/reading-and-receiving-messages/other-mobile-device-please-specify/auec25a33-4) and also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), it works service-independent for example with Blogger and Twitter but for some reason buggy with Google products such as Google Plus and Gmail.

Answer (score 9):

From [the Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gjnmclkoadjdljnfmbnnhaahilafoeji):

> "NOTE: I am aware that GmailTeX stopped working in the Compose window
>   due to recent changes in Gmail or/and Chrome. I will get around to
>   fixing it but it may take some time. Thank you for your patience."

Looks like it might be an issue that is known and being looked into.  Hopefully it gets fixed, I had no idea it existed and it seems like it might be fun to play with.

Comment: Note that the current version of GmailTeX (as of the date I am writing this comment) seems to work fine, at least in Safari.