# How to use LaTeX within the subject or body of an e-mail?

Tags: email

Does anyone have an LaTeX email template they like to use?

Is there any good way to add a LaTeX document into the subject/body of an email?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can add a letter as attachment or you can add LaTeX code as message body, but you won't be able to include the DVI/PDF in a mail without using a PDF object in HTML (which at least my mail client would block immediately). So what are you aiming at?

Comment: Use LaTeX to write the email (so that I can include math equations), and then send the email.

Comment: Then you should definitely not use LaTeX to write your mail. If it's math-heavy consider using an attachment. Otherwise you could include MathJax in a HTML mail I guess (but this would be off-topic here).

Comment: Ok understood. I wasn't sure if there was a way to include LaTeX in an email file.  Thanks

Comment: I use a Thunderbird extension called [LaTeX It!](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/latex-it/) that renders maths within `$...$` as pictures (using your local TeX installation) and embeds them in the HTML mail. It works OK for people who accept HTML mails and short maths, but if it is anything heavier I would probably just attach a PDF.

Comment: You can just put the LaTeX code in the email, which will be seen as code by the recipient. Justt that easy.

Answer (score 5):

There are (in general) two types of e-mails:

- plain text
- HTML

As your question is about the subject and the body: The subject is the same as plain text, so the following paragraph does apply.

If you want to send a plain text mail you will not be able to include LaTeX maths except by just using the LaTeX code and hoping for the recipient to compile it (or simply read it of course). In this case you basically have two options: either use Unicode math symbols (which is quite unsatisfying for everything except the most simple things) or use an attachment with a compiled LaTeX document.

With HTML mails you have way more options. You could still use Unicode symbols or attachments (or add the LaTeX code as code), but there are HTML elements that allow you to use PDF objects directly (be warned that they may be blocked by some mail clients), so you could include your compiled LaTeX document.

Furthermore, you could include images of the rendered LaTeX output into your emails. Some means of achieving this are listed in the related post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118246/how-to-send-an-email-with-latex). Please note that this is mostly client-dependent. Thunderbird, for instance, has a "Insert → Math" option in the HTML composing window, which allows to insert simple LaTeX math. Another solution for Thunderbird is the extension "LaTeX It" suggested by moewe in the comments.